# CELL("filename") linked to other workbook

Tags: excel

I have two workbooks. 
`A.xlsx` has a cell containing its own filename, and another cell containing the name of the current sheet. The formulas are:

```
=CELL("filename")                    // J1
=MID(J1, FIND("[", J1), 255)         // J2
=RIGHT(LEFT(J2, FIND("_", J2)-1), 4) // J3
=RIGHT(J2, 4)                        // J4
```

The workbooks use a naming convention so these formulas can parse the filename/sheetname reliably. Not the most robust solution, but I'm ok with it for now.

I want to link these cells from `A.xlsx` into another file: `B.xlsx`.

When I save `A.xlsx`, the cells in `B.xlsx` show the filename from `A.xlsx`, as desired.

However, when I save `B.xlsx`, the value shows B's filename instead of A's; this is not what I want.

To make matters worse, saving B causes the text in A to show B's filename!

Is there a way to do a one-way link (not sure what it would be called in Excel) to get an introspective value from A to show up in B?

Comment: try adding a reference: `=CELL("filename",A1)`

Comment: The purpose of CELL("filename") is to bring the workbook's name into a cell. If you want another workbook's name you can't use the CELL() function. If you want a particular file name that never changes the best method is to **not** use a function to find it.

Comment: I tested `=CELL("filename", '[My Workbook.xlsx]Sheet1'!A1)` and the function returned the filename of the specified cell. The question is why you would specify the filename in a formula so that it would return the filename.

Comment: Adding the reference fixes it for me. @ScottCraner add this as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is helpful.  Thanks.
The reason I use it is that first 4 characters of file value a year that is used in spreadsheet.
If you are willing to go to VBA, a simple user-defined function can neatly do the job:

```
Public Function ThisFile(Optional WithPath As Boolean) As String
'this function must be in workbook where it is used (not in Personal.xlsb)
'WithPath in spreadsheet can be omitted with parentheses blank or 0 in parentheses to get just filename
'WithPath in spreadsheet can be 1 in parentheses to get full path
If WithPath = True Then
    ThisFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName 'returns full path and filename with extension
Else
    ThisFile = ThisWorkbook.Name ' returns filename and extension without path
End If
End Function
```